# Online resources for Introduction to computer and computer sciences for absolute beginner

Tags: python, computer-science, computer-science-theory

In our office, we have an office boy(completed high school(10+2 years)) with average academic record so far). He wants to learn programming. I have started coaching him in Computer Science basics (history of computer science, number systems, etc.), but I am not able to put in enough time with him(because I have very limited free time and more importantly I do not want to spoon feed him). Now I am not sure how to fill in the gap of theoretical reading.

Now my question is, could anyone point me to some online resources(preferably in simple English) for Introduction to Computer Sciences.

Moreover, I am planning to start him with on programming with book Think Like A Computer Scientist - Python version. If any body knows a better book or an online resource - preferably in Python, please point out.

Thanks

Comment: Its the Indian system of education. 10 years of High School plus 2 years of Senior Secondary School where one choose 5 specific subjects from Science, Arts, Commerce, Humanities or other Vocational streams. I am not aware of US or European equivalent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally decided to use a mixture of online resources. I am teaching him basics of CS and basic Python myself. Then I will cherry pick topics for him from various free python books and official documentations.

Let's see how this experiment goes.

Answer (score 1):

I learnt to program by myself with nothing more than the web to aid me. If he's serious about learning then he shouldn't need much teaching. You might start by pointing him to http://docs.python.org/tutorial/

Answer (score 1):

http://learnpythonthehardway.org/index might be useful.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.testandtrack.io/ is one of the best resources to use. It covers a lot of basic concepts and as a student was a life saver for exams. There is also a lot of extracurricular knowledge that helped further my love for the subject.

Answer (score 0):

[Finxter](https://www.finxter.com) is based on a puzzle-based learning method from beginner to advanced level. Users solve rated python puzzles and watch learning videos. Computer Science concepts are fed on-the-go (*learning-by-doing*). Here you can see an example puzzle I created:

[image]